# Looking to assign print output (string) to a variable

Tags: python

I've been struggling for the past 2 days to do something that I am sure is easy. Unfortunately I do not know python very well (nearly nothing actually) and I'm just trying to edit a script for work.

Basically it should look into a folder, get the filename and assign the filename to a variable. But everything I tried failed  :

```
filepath = "/folder/*.*/"
for path in glob.glob(filepath):
  dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
  print(filename)[0:-19]

var1 = filename
var2 = filename[0:-25]
```

I tried with

```
var1 = str(filename)
```

But nothing works. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do with `[0:-19]` and `[0:-25]`. Without it I manage to get all filenames present in all matching folders (easily editable to save the names into variables). If it's what you want, I can put the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that your code is written now, it prints however many file names for the number of files in your folder, discards the `filename` variable and runs again on a new path.  When you have a `for` loop, the variables are discarded on every iteration to make way for the new ones.  So this code:

```
filepath = "/folder/*.*/"

for path in glob.glob(filepath):
    dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
    print( filename )[0:-19]

Var1 = filename
Var2 = filename[0:-25]
```

is running for each path you supply it with initially, then keeps **only the last filename** when you refer back to it in the `vars`.  I think what you want is something like this:

```
for path in filepath:
  dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
  print(filename[0:-19])
  var1 = filename
  var2 = filename[0:-25]
```

From there, you could do anything you want with `var1` and `var2`.

Comment: That did it !Thank you very much !

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

```
def GetFileList(FindPath,FlagStr=[]):  
    ''''' 
    #>>>FlagStr=['F','EMS','txt'] # Characters need to include
    #>>>FileList=GetFileList(FindPath,FlagStr) # 
    '''  
    import os  
    FileList=[]  
    FileNames=os.listdir(FindPath)  
    if (len(FileNames)>0):  
        for fn in FileNames:  
            if (len(FlagStr)>0):  
                #return Specified filename  
                if (IsSubString(FlagStr,fn)):  
                    fullfilename=os.path.join(FindPath,fn)  
                    FileList.append(fullfilename)  
            else:  
                #return all filename  
                fullfilename=os.path.join(FindPath,fn)  
                FileList.append(fullfilename)  

     #sort filename
     if (len(FileList)>0):  
         FileList.sort()  

     return FileList
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a simple indentation issue. Currently, `var1` and `var2` are *outside* the for loop. I didn't study your script or its output thoroughly but doing what I've done below will assign the value of `filename` to `var1` and assign a section of filename (from the beginning to the character 25 places from the end) to `var2`.

```
filepath = "/folder/*.*/"
for path in glob.glob(filepath):
  dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
  print(filename)[0:-19]
  var1 = filename
  var2 = filename[0:-25]
  print(var1)
  print(var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and work from there:

```
import os

filepath = "/"

var1 = os.listdir(filepath)
var2 = os.listdir(filepath)[2]

print var1
print
print var2
```